# How do I run a Javascript code at the first time of loading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS function to calculate given data multiply by another input data.

```
var item1unitp = 150;
var item2unitp = 320;

function total () {

    var x1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
    var x1p = parseInt(x1);
    var tot1 = item1unitp * x1p;

    var x2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
    var x2p = parseInt(x2);
    var tot2 = item2unitp * x2p;

    var tot = tot1+tot2;

    document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = tot;
}
```

and my HTML

```
Item 1 : <input type="text" id="t1" value="1" onkeyup="total();"/> <br/><br/>

Item 2 : <input type="text" id="t2" value="1" onkeyup="total();"/> <br/><br/>

Sub Total : <span id="tot"></span>
```

This code is working but at the beginning of the page this span is showing nothing. But I already added value 1 to each input. How I get an initial subtotal at the beginning???

Comment: You run the function, by just adding `total()` somewhere **after** the elements in the DOM

Comment: can you more specific??

Comment: The simplest method it to put this just before the `</body>` tag: `<script>total();</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what u are expecting please tell me if it is wrong.

```
Sub Total : <span id="tot" value="total()"></span>
<script>
var item1unitp = 150;
var item2unitp = 320;

function total() {

  var x1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
  var x1p = parseInt(x1);
  var tot1 = item1unitp * x1p;
  var x2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
  var x2p = parseInt(x2);
  var tot2 = item2unitp * x2p;
  var tot = tot1+tot2;

  document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = tot;
  return tot;
}
total();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. We set the function `total` to be called when the page loads. It's also good practice to set the event handlers for `onkeyup` in the JS rather than HTML. This is to separate the layout and the behavior of the website, so I've done that as well.

HTML

```
Item 1 : <input type="text" id="t1" value="1" /> <br/> <br/> 
Item 2 : <input type="text" id="t2" value="1" /> <br/> <br/> 
Sub Total : <span id="tot"></span>
```

JS

```
var item1unitp = 150;
var item2unitp = 320;

t1.onkeyup = total;
t2.onkeyup = total;
window.onload = total;

function total(){

    var x1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
    var x1p = parseInt(x1);
    var tot1 = item1unitp * x1p;

    var x2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
    var x2p = parseInt(x2);
    var tot2 = item2unitp * x2p;

    var tot = tot1+tot2;

    document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = tot;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y5pgrcc4/